# Validation errors disappear after render 'new'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a nested form which captures information for two models, **Games and Teams**.

**My Models:**

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :teams
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :teams
    validates_associated :teams
    validates :start_time, presence: true
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :game
    validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
end
```

Before saving the records, the validations must be passed. If the save fails, the form should be re-rendered and the validation error messages displayed, as per the controller below. However, the error messages never get displayed.

**My GamesController:**

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @game = Game.new
        @team = @game.teams.build
    end

    def create  
        @game = Game.new(game_params)

        unless @game.save
            render 'new'
            return
        end

        # Some other code that shouldn't run if the save fails, hence the 'return' above
        
    end
end
```

**My form *(new.html.erb):***

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %> 

<%= form_with model: @game do |f| %>
<%= f.fields_for :teams do |f_teams| %>

<%= f_teams.label :name %>
<%= f_teams.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'%>

<%= f.label :start_time, "Game day" %>
<%= f.date_field :start_time, id: "game_day", class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.submit "Book now!", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
<% end %>
```

and finally, **the error message partial:**

```
<% if @game.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alertdanger">
        The form contains <%= pluralize(@game.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
        <% @game.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
```

When I deliberately trip up the validations (e.g. by not including the game day) the error message partial doesn't run, presumably because the ***@game.errors.any?*** is false.

If I use byebug or if I go throug the rails console, I get the validation errors, e.g. *start_time can't be blank*.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

Chris's solution below worked for me. However, I wanted my controller to run JS if validations were met and save succeeded. So I went back and removed the suggested `local: true` and allowed the remote submission to happen. What I did to fix the issue is render html if save didn't succeed:

```
unless @game.save
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {   render 'new' }
    end
    return
end
```

This didn't work out of the box because turbolinks interferes. I therefore ended up adding `gem 'turbolinks_render'` to my Gemfile and **voila** everthing works great now.

Huge shoutout to Joel (https://joelc.io/ajax-ruby-on-rails-forms) for the walkthrough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your new.html.erb file, try

```
<%= form_with(model: @game, local: true) do |f| %>
```

Some good info for using the `form_with` tag here:
https://medium.com/@tinchorb/form-with-building-html-forms-in-rails-5-1-f30bd60ef52d

Comment: By setting local: true my form is no longer submitted remotely (it says so on the tin, I get that!) but I believe that has some negative consequences for my app, e.g. my js.erb file doesn't load at the end of the controller's create action. So aollow up question @chris: Is there a way to do the re-rendering of form with validation errors without using a local submission. Or, alternatively, is there a way to have the js.erb file run after a local submission? Thank you for any feedback